# setlocale doesnt work for am or pm in specific time format

Tags: php, locale, strftime

I am using setlocale to convert the time to different language.  The date format works fine in english language.  Also Its working fine for month for different locale but its not showing 'am' or 'pm'.

Below is my code:

```
 setlocale(LC_TIME,'nl_NL');
 echo strftime("%h %d, %G - %I:%M %P","UNIX TIME");
```

for "en_US" as locale: output is : Oct 10,2011 08:19 AM
for "nl_NL" as locale: outpupt is : Okt 10,2011 08:19

As per the above output: AM is missing in different locale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you run a command at a PHP prompt "locale -a" and check the locales currently installed in your machine.

If you see a Dutch locale installed and using it does not return you the result that you'd need then I suggest installing a different Dutch locale.